# Удаление нескольких выбранных элементов ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Программа устроена так, что каждый объект имеет свойство **isSelected** (boolean), которым помечаются элементы списка для удаления.
Следующий код должен отвечать за удаление всех элементов с **isSelected = true** из адаптера.

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            if (Objects.requireNonNull(adapter.getItem(i)).isSelected) {
                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Но в итоге удаляется лишь один элемент, а не все сразу.

Comment: Вы удаляете элемент 1, а затем переходите к элементу 2 (а бывший элемент 2 сместился после удаления на позицию 1, т.е. вы его просто пропускаете и переходите сразу к бывшему элементу 3). Плюс, находящийся в цикле notifyDataSetChanged будет тормозить работу списка. Вынесите за цикл notifyDataSetChanged и измените логику удаления или попробуйте перейти на ListAdapter https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/recyclerview-more-animations-with-less-code-using-support-library-listadapter-62e65126acdb, который реализует за вас логику удаления из списка и анимацию этого удаления.

Comment: Благодарю) Там действительно всего-то нужно было декрементировать **i** после каждого удаления.